# Call a method from different classes based on an input parameter

Tags: java, arrays, class, variables, call

I'm making a textadventure in Java and I try to make a "Mission board". There you can see available missions, but I don't know how I should call the methods in other classes with a variable. I tried something like this:

```
int quest[] = new int[20];
int i = 0; // running variable

if (quest1Done == false) {
    quest[i] = 1;
}
switch (br.readLine()) {
   case "1": Quest+quest[0]+.run(); //this should run the method run() in the class Quest + variable (in that case 1)
}
```

All class names are called "Quest"+a number.

Comment: I'm programming in java

Comment: You might want to take a step back and skim some Java tutorials. If you have an instance of a `Quest`, and `run()` takes a parameter, it'd be `theQuest.run(quest[0])`. If it doesn't, then you need to provide details about the method you're trying to run.

Comment: @RedBaron You could either use reflection or take advantage of polymorphism to achieve this.

Comment: @DaveNewton The OP wants to dynamically invoke a method based on input.

Comment: Thank you all, I found out a way to do this.

Comment: @RedBaron I believe you want a way to dynamically call the methods based on the value present in the file. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can begin by defining an interface called `QuestRunner` and make sure all your `Quest` classes implement this interface and the `run` method :

```
public interface QuestRunner { 
     public void run();
}
```

You now have 2 options to dynamically call a method based on the line present in the file :

**1. Reflection**

Create a method that creates an object for you based on the fully qualified name of a class :

```
public void runQuest(String className) {
     try {
          Class classDefinition = Class.forName(className);
          Object obj = classDefinition.newInstance();
          if(obj instanceof QuestRunner) { ((QuestRunner)obj).run();
      } catch (InstantiationException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      }

   }
```

**2. Runtime polymorphism**

You can have a method that returns an appropriate `QuestRunner` implementation given the line number :

```
public static QuestRunner createQuestRunner(String lineNum) {
   QuestRunner questRunner = null;
   if(lineNumber.equals("1")) { questRunner = new Quest1() } 
   else if(lineNumber.equals("2")) { ..... }
   return questRunner;
}
```

You can then simply pass the lineNumber to this method and call the `run` method :

```
QuestRunner questRunner = createQuestRunner(br.readLine());
questRunner.run();
```

**Note** : You no longer need the switch case if you use the above solutions.

Comment: I found out a similar solution, but thanks for your effort :)

Comment: @RedBaron That's great. In that case I believe my answer is correct so do accept it and upvote for other users to know that this is the solution. We don't provide answers for a thanks you know :)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to think about the structure of your code. What you are trying to do is incorrect. An optional version of what you are trying to accomplish would be:

- You have an instance of the game you are trying to build.
- You store.
  your missions in ArrayList full with your Quest's
- You have a method "run" in the game.
  instance that gets as a parameter id of the quest you would like to
  run and executes it.

In that example you could do the following:

```
Game mGame = new Game(Quest a, Quest b, Quest c); // In the game constructor you add these quests to your ArrayList
mGame.run(1); // runs quest with id = 1
```

That's just super basic idea of how you can achieve the functionality you expect from your program.